# Can we add two index in same graph in kibi beta version?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

i created two index in Elasticsearch , now i want to visuallize these two index in same graph on kibi in line chart,is there any way to visuallize in kibi?

Answer (score 0):

Kibana doesnot support multiple index visualization, but you can use elasticsearch alias that can help you here [Click here for more info](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html)

Alternativly, you need to name your index as such that you can follow wild card pattern to select both index

Hope this helps